# Sudden drop in performance of hash table

Tags: hashtable

I recently implemented an algorithm in Java that used a hash table. I compared it to a few other algorithms with rather large data input sizes such as 100000.

The thing that has struck me is that once my data input size exceeds 10000 the performance of the hash table drops dramatically. To emphasise this drop, what took 4000 ms with input size 1000 suddenly goes up to 172000 ms for input size 5000.

Can anyone please explain to me what the reason for this is? I'd really like to know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is that you're actually doing with the hashtable?  Are there other aspects of your algorithm/data that could cause the performance drop, rather than the hashtable itself?

Comment: could be an open addressing gone bad. maybe related to vm max mem size ?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: I was using it just to match elements and once they were matched I removed them from the hashtable. So the hashtable grew and shrunk continuously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is way too ambiguous for anyone to give a definitive answer, but if I had to guess I would say that you are encountering *collisions*. The stock implementation of java's HashMap uses linked lists to hold the entries whose keys' hashes collide, which will certainly happen if the hashCode method has been incorrectly defined; perhaps returning a constant value.

Having said that, if you're just measuring elapsed time, that doesn't tell you too much.  Perhaps you crossed a threshold that caused a major garbage collection to occur.  You should try to measure performance after your JVM and hash table are sufficiently warmed up, and take lots of measurements and consider their average, before coming to any conclusions.

Comment: If the keys are identical, that's not really a hash collision, that's just "putting the same thing into the table twice".  It won't result in extra storage or longer linked lists.

Comment: The same thing is not put into the table twice - there is only allowed one instance of a value in the hash table.